# How to get the url for index.php in symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

How can I get the index.php's url in symfony 1.4?

I know there is a function `url_for()` but it only returns the given plugin's url. I want to get the url which routes to index.php

This cannot be a constant since the domain and paths may change.

Comment: Why do you need to know url for `index.php`?

Comment: to record it in a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo public_path('index.php');
```

This code uses `public path` function from [UrlHelper](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/UrlHelper#method_public_path). It will only work inside a template.